# Is it possible to change an existing list's URL?

Tags: powershell, administration

Is it possible to change a list's URL from something like /site/Lists/ListName to /site/ListName in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using the following PowerShell commands:

```
$site = Get-SPWeb https://server.name/site/
$site.Lists["ListName"].RootFolder.MoveTo("ListName")
```

Normally, the MoveTo method would take an argument like "Lists/ListName", but when it's passed just the list name it moves the list to the root of the site. This command can also be used to change the URL of the list, e.g., MoveTo("NewName") would change the URL to /site/NewName.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah sure,

- via SharePoint Designer 2010 Click go for All Files view.
- Click on Lists and from the left pane expand lists and then locate
  the list for which the URL has to be changed.
- Then right click on    the list name and from the context menu click
  Rename.
- Changing here is also reflected in the URL change

Comment: Sorry, I should have framed the question differently. I would like to move the list out of the the "Lists" folder, thus changing the URL of the list.

Comment: The "Lists" folder is actually "virtual" (a simple path). One could create a list directly under the site, therefore changing URL would do that too. It is much easier though when you start with a new list definition.